# Django Selenium PhantomJS form not submitting

Tags: python, django, forms, selenium, phantomjs

In my Django app, I switched my WebDrver from Firefox to PhantomJS. However, my test no longer successfully submits forms.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
    super(CreateLevelTestCase, self).setUp()

def test_know_all_the_words(self):
    self.driver.get(self.live_server_url)
    self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("form").submit()
    time.sleep(1)
    self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("form").submit()
    time.sleep(1)
    self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("form").submit()
    time.sleep(1)
    self.assertNotEqual(self.driver.current_url.find("/my/stats"), -1) # Test that the page changed.
```

**UPDATE:** Here's the form submit code:

```
$('#testform').live('submit', function(e){
    $("#progressbar").show().find('.progress').addClass('active').find('.bar').css('width', '100%');
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(res){
        if (res.success && !res.end) {
            $('#testform input[name="test"]').val(res.current_test);
            $("#progressbar .progress").removeClass('active').find('.bar').css('width', parseInt(res.current_test / 3.0 * 100) + '%');
            $('#text').text(res.text).attr('data-simp', res.text).attr('data-trad', res.text_trad);
            readiness();
        } else if (res.success && res.end){
            window.location = res.text;
        } else {
            alert(res.errors)
        }
    }, 'json')
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; 
});
```

**Update 2**: Ghostdriver Log

```
[ERROR - 2015-06-30T00:38:37.036Z] Session [54ea6630-1ec0-11e5-9b65-095407f6737e] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'a')

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-06-30T00:38:37.036Z] Session [54ea6630-1ec0-11e5-9b65-095407f6737e] - page.onError - stack:
  (anonymous function) (http://localhost:8081/static/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js:6)

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-06-30T00:38:37.037Z] Session [54ea6630-1ec0-11e5-9b65-095407f6737e] - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-06-30T00:38:37.037Z] Session [54ea6630-1ec0-11e5-9b65-095407f6737e] - page.onError - stack:
  global code (http://localhost:8081/:186)

  :262 in error
```

The main page is a test whose contents change upon submitting the form three times. After the form has been submitted for the final time, the test is complete and we show the user a stats page.

When I use webdriver.Firefox(), the test works fine. However, when I use PhantomJS, the current_url referenced in assertNotEqual is still http://localhost:8081.

What is going on?

Comment: You're probably using some function that PhantomJS doesn't support during form validation. Have you tried PhantomJS 2?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript front end? Some of these, most notably React, don't currently work with PhantomJS.

Comment: Added the JavaScript associated with submitting the form.

Comment: These is nothing out of the ordinary in the submit handler. It seems that you load data dynamically, so you need to wait for the data to be loaded. alecxe's answer must have worked with the explicit wait. Maybe it wasn't long enough.

Comment: Ten seconds is a really long time. Also, that wouldn't explain the difference between PhantomJS and Firefox here.

Comment: Anything on the console?

Comment: @Huey Well, the JavaScript code on the page is not executing properly. I don't know what you are using on your page but, to take an example, a misconfigured RequireJS setup may work fine in a browser but fail in another because a race condition caused by the bad configuration becomes problematic only in the 2nd browser.

Comment: Didn't see anything on the console, but your comment seems helpful. I'll look to see if there are any problems with the JS.